# Python "with" Keyword in Lambda Functions

Tags: python, lambda

How is Python's `with` keyword expressed in a lambda function? Consider the following:

```
def cat (filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        return f.read()
```

A failed attempt at a lambda implementation:

```
cat = lambda filename: with open(filename, 'r') as f: return f.read()
```

Comment: Using CPython, your file will be closed immediately after the line `open(filename).read()` is executed, because the file object is immediately garbage collected.  This is an expression and could be used in a lambda.  But this is poor style and not a good use case for lambda anyway, using the `def` is better.

Comment: Thanks for the input. So for this example, you would simply write `open(filename).read()` wherever it was needed?

Comment: you _could_, which is different from _would_   :)

Comment: @StephenNiedzielski Remember that people may run this code on Jython or IronPython for example, which need the actual closing of the file otherwise they have to wait for their garbage collector

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> `lambda_form     ::=  "lambda" [parameter_list]: expression`

You can't, `with` is a statement, and `lambda` only returns expressions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there an alternative for `with` in the same manner as there is for `if`? Or is a standard function most practical?

Comment: @StephenNiedzielski A standard function, `lambda`s weren't built for this, Guido also despises them.

Comment: for reasons like this, where people try to use `lambda`s in place of normal functions when they just look less readable. They are useful in some situations, `itertools.dropwhile` for example,  but try not to use them when you can.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is if you are assigning the lambda to a name (like you are here, with `cat`) then something is fishy and it should usually be a `def` instead.  Sometimes lambdas are needed as function call arguments, but even here they are overused and there's often a better alternative.

Comment: Stephen, remember that you can use local functions, in case you forgot. The new function doesn't have to pollute the global/module namespace.

Comment: @doomster, that's what I'm sticking with. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case somebody is looking for a trick:

`lambda filename: [(f.read(), f.close()) for f in [open(filename)]][0][0]`

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question

Comment: `lambda filename: (f:=open(filename),f.read(),f.close())[1]` (python 3.8)